# Need solution to expose details in table without destroying layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently looking for a solution allowing me to display a lot of log output in a compact, easy to read way. The goal is to hide as many information as possible until they become of interest since we need to display thousands of lines of log output.

I already succeeded in keeping our tables from going to a width of 2800px with introducing divs inside td's. Now I want to expose the full information to the user once he hovers over the div, but without destroying the layout of the table and without needing to have all information two times in the code, since the html already nears 3-4 MByte.

It's okay to use Javascript and/or JQuery but I'm new to it and am currently stuck.

Here is a small simplified example of the html code.

```
    <head>
        <title>expose full details</title>
        <style>
            #codeline { width:150px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
            #fullline { background: #EEE; z-index: 10; display: hidden; }
            #loglines { width:250px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td>PASS</td>
        <td>2012-10-10 09:30:31</td>
        <td><div id="codeline">c:\myfiles\are\not\stored\here\testscript.py:line434</div></td>
        <td><div id="loglines">Here is a very long log output that might continue for 10-20 lines</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FAIL</td>
        <td>2012-10-10 09:30:32</td>
        <td><div id="codeline">c:\myfiles\are\not\stored\here\testscript.py:line439</div></td>
        <td><div id="loglines">Here is another very long log output that might continue for 10-20 lines</div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Every hint is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: look into jquery dialog , or modal-dialog , you can easily have the data pop-up with out changing the table

Comment: Hi Scott, I think the jquery ui tooltip is more what I am looking for, but I have not yet figured out how I can avoid data in the "title" attribute of the div. There must be a way that the data is taken from the div it hovers over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reread this I had a typo in code something put an extra quote in, and I said clarified the id and class a bit, I misspoke in there and said style when I mean class...

First off you need to be aware of a few things.
id="somename" should be a unique value throughout an entire document, if you want to group items to style them the same use class="somename" and reference it with a . instead of a # in your CSS.

You were not clear exactly where you want the data to be displayed, I believe this is what you were looking to do, you can use absolute positioning of the #fullline code to put it where you want. I read a comment you made about wanting to do this tooltip style which you could do with absolute positioning (dynamically adjusted in the showdtl section, but from what it sounds like you are wanting to do a static placement of the text would be best. I changed the width of the full line so you can see it properly expands as needed.
fullline being a unique id in your code I left alone, to illustrate usage of class and id.
I just tossed this together, it works but I'm sure it will require a bit of tweaking on your end to get the desired result.

```
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>expose full details</title>         
      <style>             
          .codeline { width:150px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }             
          #fullline { background: #FFCC66; z-index: 10; width: 250; display: hidden;  }             
          .loglines { width:250px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;}
      </style>     
    </head>

  <body>     
<script>
function showdtl(passedobj){
fullline.style.display = '';
fullline.innerHTML=passedobj.innerHTML;
}
function hidedtl(){
fullline.style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
      <table style="border:1px solid black;">     
          <tr>         
              <td>PASS</td>
              <td>2012-10-10 09:30:31</td>
              <td><div class="codeline">c:\myfiles\are\not\stored\here\testscript.py:line434</div></td>         
              <td><div class="loglines" onMouseOver="showdtl(this);return true" onMouseOut="hidedtl();return true" >Here is a very long log output that might continue for 10-20 lines</div></td>
          </tr>     
          <tr>         
              <td>FAIL</td>  
              <td>2012-10-10 09:30:32</td>         
              <td><div class="codeline">c:\myfiles\are\not\stored\here\testscript.py:line439</div></td>         
              <td><div class="loglines" onMouseOver="showdtl(this);return true" onMouseOut="hidedtl();return true">Here is another very long log output that might continue for 10-20 lines</div></td>
          </tr>     
      </table>         

<div id="fullline">

</div>    


    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably allow these divs to scroll if they are huge:

```
#codelines, #loglines {overflow: auto; width: 250px; max-height: 500px }
```

overflow:auto will only display a scroll bar if necessary, so it looks much better than overflow:scroll. Letting them scroll a 500px (or 800, whatever) box of logging is much nicer than having a giant webpage with additional info hidden way down.

EDIT:

If you really want this to only be available on hover you could use this:

```
#codelines:hover, #loglines:hover { overflow: hidden; width: 250px; max-height: 500px }
#codelines:hover, #loglines:hover {overflow: auto}
```

I've never really seen that done though.

Comment: Thx Muirbot, but the scrollbars do not really work for me, it needs to much user interaction to get the whole picture, and the text is still shortened from the ellipsis. The goal is to make it easy for the poor guys that have to check hundreds of loglines per day.